# Redirect / pipe into read command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, pipe, zsh

This is a follow-up to my previous question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958028/stdout-race-condition-between-script-and-subscript). I am still trying to command a script `deepScript` from within another script `shallowScript` and process its output before display on terminal. Here is a code sample:

**deepScript.sh**

```
#!/bin/zsh
print "Hello - this is deepScript"
read "ans?Reading : "
print $ans
```

**shallowScript.sh**

```
#!/bin/zsh

function __process {
    while read input; do
        echo $input | sed "s/e/E/g"
    done }

print "Hello - this is shallowScript"
. ./deepScript.sh |& __process
```

*(edited : outcome of this syntax and of 2 alternatives pasted below)*

**[UPDATE]**

I have tried alternative syntaxes for last redirection `. ./deepScript.sh |& __process` and each syntax has a different outcome, but of course none of them is the one I want. I'll just paste each syntax and the resulting output of `./shallowScript.sh` (where I typed "input" when `read` was waiting for an input), together with my findings so far.

**Option 1 :** `. ./deepScript.sh |& __process`

From this [link](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/blog/?p=178), it seems that `. ./deepScript.sh` is run from a subshell, but not `__process`. Output:

```
zsh : ./shallowScript.sh
Hello - this is shallowScript
HEllo - this is dEEpScript
input
REading : input
```

Basically, the first two lines are printed as expected, then instead of printing the prompt `REading :`, the script directly waits for the stdin input, and **then** prints the prompt and executes `print $ans`.

**Option 2:** `__process < <(. ./deepScript.sh)`

Zsh's [manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution) indicates that `(. ./deepScript.sh)` will run as a subprocess. To me, that looks similar to *Option 1*. Output:

```
Hello - this is shallowScript
Reading : HEllo - this is dEEpScript
input
input
```

So, *within* `. ./deepScript.sh`, it prints read's prompt (script line 3) before the print (script line 2). Strange.

**Option 3:** `__process < =(. ./deepScript.sh)`

According to the same [manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution), `(. ./deepScript.sh)` here sends its output to a temp file, which is then injected in `__process` (I don't know if there is a subprocess or not). Output:

```
Hello - this is shallowScript
Reading : input
HEllo - this is dEEpScript
input
```

Again, deepScript's line 3 prints to the terminal before line 2, but now it waits for the read to be complete.

Two questions:

- Should this be expected?
- Is there a fix or a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed delay stems from two factors:

1. `deepScript.sh` and `process` run asynchronously
2. `read` reads a complete line before returning

`deepScript.sh` writes the prompt to standard error, but without a newline. It then waits for your input while `process` continues to wait for a full line to be written so that its call to `read` can finish.

Comment: chepner, is there any workaround that you can recommend?

Comment: I'd suggest not trying to process standard output and standard error simultaneously. They are two separate streams, and any attempt to merge them (by piping both into the same command) will cause them to be interleaved in a non-deterministic fashion. What does `__process` *really* do that it needs to process both?

Comment: actually, the only reason why I thought about this was because `read` prints its prompt to stderr (at least zsh's builtin read). But I can live without that; anyway, in options 2 and 3 above I only tried to send `deepScript`'s stdout to `__process`, with the funky results copied above.    In real life, `__process` does some `sed` on the output + some logging depending on presence of certain patterns.    It seems that with `read` waiting for an `\n` I'll have to find a workaround.